# How to add class to ID of link href

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add class "visible" to a div with the same ID as my link's hrefs, which also has class "popup". Here's my code so far:

```
    <a href="#about">Sample link</a>
    <div id="#about" class="popup">Sample content</div>  

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").click(function(event){
             event.preventDefault();

             var id = $this.attr('href');
             $('id.popup').addClass("visible");
        });
        });
    </script>
```

I've tried many variations of the ID.popup combo but I can't seem to get the targeting right.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to add `tabindex="-1"` to the `<div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to fix these lines

```
var id = $this.attr('href');
$('id.popup').addClass("visible");

<div id="#about" class="popup">Sample content</div>
```

to

```
var id = $(this).attr('href');
$(id + '.popup').addClass("visible");

<div id="about" class="popup">Sample content</div>  <-- remove # from id
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually just used $(id + '.popup').addClass("visible"); and it worked!